# QAbstractListModel to Combobox , How to get value a When select value b

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qabstractlistmodel

I have made very simple QAbstractListModel example.This example also presented on this link : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-models-abstractitemmodel-example.html . An program result is like this:

[program result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9iiJ.png)
I have made a little change on it on view.qml like this

```
ComboBox {
id:mycombo
width: 200; height: 250

model: myModel
textrole:"type"
onCurrentTextChanged: {

   console.log(mycombo.model.get(currentIndex).size);
}
}
```

on here , Combobox shows animals type.But I want to write 'size' value when onCurrentTextChanged event. But I can't get type value.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a failure in your cpp model implementation.
Because when i use a qml model it works as it should:

```
ListModel {
    id: myModel
    ListElement{
        type: "mouse"
        size: "small"
    }
    ListElement{
        type: "cat"
        size:"medium"

    }
    ListElement{
        type: "elephant"
        size:"large"
    }
}

ComboBox {
    id:mycombo
    width: 200; height: 250

    model: myModel
    textRole:"type"

    onCurrentTextChanged: {
       console.log(mycombo.model.get(currentIndex).size);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
qml: small
qml: medium
qml: large
```